# form problem with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

the scenario is I am generating a test. There is a countdown clock. When this countdown is finished the form is submitted.

so currently if I complete the test normally etc, and submit my results myself it all works fine.

this is my statement which triggers the form submission when the countdown is up:

```
if(Todays_Date >= Target_Date){
        alert("Timeup, Submitting exam....");
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        $("form#testForm").submit();
    }
```

what I am currently getting is if statement fires successfully and the alert pops up, however it appears nothing else happens, i.e it doesn't navigate to the action page.

form details:

`<form id="testForm" method="post" action="add_responses.php">`

now I am quite a noob, so does using submit() not actually follow the action page? do I have to tell the software to send to the page or what? (window location etc)

many thanks,

**EDIT:** added a bit more code:

```
// TEST COUNTDOWN CLOCK
function countdown(timestamp) {
    timetarget = new Date(timestamp);

    var Today = new Date();

    var Todays_Date = Today.getTime();
    var Target_Date = timetarget.getTime();

    var tester = new Date(Target_Date);

    //Find their difference, and convert that into seconds.
    var Time_Left = Math.round((Target_Date - Todays_Date) / 1000);

    if(Todays_Date >= Target_Date){
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        $("form#testForm").submit();
        alert("Timeup, Submitting exam....");
    }

    //More datailed.
    days = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60 * 24));     
    Time_Left %= (60 * 60 * 24);
    hours = Math.floor(Time_Left / (60 * 60));
    Time_Left %= (60 * 60);
    minutes = Math.floor(Time_Left / 60);
    Time_Left %= 60;
    seconds = Time_Left;

    if(hours == 0 && minutes < 10){
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.color='red';
        }

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    html = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' secs';

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = html;

    //Recursive call, keeps the clock ticking.
    var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() { countdown(timestamp); }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, It just simply gets stuck, every second bringing up the alert.

Comment: I hope the person doing the exam doesn't know Javascript. ;-)

Comment: Well in all seriousness, it is useful, there is a big flaw in your system; if your Javascript fails, people get as much time as they like to complete an exam. That doesn't sound good. Anyway, we need to see the rest of your code surrounding that if statement, because it's likely where that is placed that's causing the alert to keep popping up.

Comment: ok so that is a useful comment. stating something is naff and not explaining, is not a useful comment.

Comment: Gary presents a very good point, you know...

Comment: i know he does, however for time sake, ive done it this way, so I don't have time to change it. Also out of interest, how would you suggest doing it?

Comment: Ok explanation; `javascript:document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('id', 'i_want_as_much_time_as_i_like_to_complete_this_exam_mwuhahaha');` your system fails because the form won't be found with your Javascript code. This kind of logic should have fail safes on the server side.

Comment: ok so I have added the code for the whole js function.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

As I suspected it's because of where you've placed your if statement, and general ordering of code.

Once the form is submitted, it keeps heading down the code and back onto the setTimeout.

The easiest thing to do would be to just add a return statement inside your if;

```
if(Todays_Date >= Target_Date){
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $("form#testForm").submit();
    alert("Timeup, Submitting exam....");
    return; // <-- add this so the code below isn't excuted again.
}
```

---

As some side notes, and as explained in my comments, this kind of logic belongs on the server side, as relying on the Javascript will cause serious implications and flaws in your system:

- Users with Javascript knowledge can hack your system into getting as much time to complete an exam as they like: i.e. `javascript:document.getElementById('testForm').setAttribute('id', 'i_want_as_much_time_as_i_like_to_complete_this_exam_mwuhahaha');`

This point alone is just unacceptable for a system such as this (unless this is a silly questionnaire or something of insignificance, but for real exams, such as uni work or something -- it needs serious rethinking)

### An alternative

Well it's interesting to design such a system as this because your doing something instinctively intrusive; demanding a user submit their form in the allocated time. But let's but this into perspective; when your in a real exam you don't allocate the time you have, it's set, simple as that. When you hand in coursework; you have a deadline. When that isn't met, tough luck. Bottom line is **the user has to take responsibility for submitting their work in and on time.**

### Techniques

- **Database & Server Side Logic:** Store the deadline date in the database for that paticular user, relational to that exam id. If the user tries to submit after that time, the server simply won't allow it.
- **Saving Drafts/Not Losing Data:** Split the exam up across multiple pages and force the user to submit to get onto the next page. This will mean the server has chance to save the exam state so far.
- **How the user knows how long they have & the consequences:** On each page have a fixed div bar which shows the deadline time, so the user knows exactly how long they have got and warn them of the consequences of not submitting their form on time.
- **Javascript as a polite informer and submitter:** You can continue to do what your doing of submitting the form once the deadline is reached, and even have a countdown on the fixed bar running across the screen that countdowns in realtime the timeleft. The difference is that the server knows whether to accept latecomers or not; so the Javascript doesn't decide, nor does the user.

[image: Example of informing the user how long they have left]

Comment: yep, unfortunately I don't have time to change the whole approach to my test. I can however write about such flaws in my report after. However want to get this test submitting successfully and I don't understand why it is carrying out code after the form is supposed to have been submitted, and therefore the user on a different page.

Comment: ok so I have tried this, I have also tried reordering so the timeout is declared before, thus not restarting the timeout. However still no form submission. The alert pops up, timer stops at 0. Nothing else. :(

Comment: Try `$('#testForm').get(0).submit();`

Comment: Ok just for some debugging, can you do `alert($('#testForm').length);`

Comment: Are there any events on the submit input element or any events being attached to the form? I think this is one of those cases where we need to see your whole code. Can you put it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: i have another clock running on the page thinking about it, which is just the time. would that affect it?

Comment: Not sure. Can you paste your whole HTML code and Javascript on www.jsfiddle.net -- click "save" and paste the url

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Cnvc/8/ this is as much as I can get going on jsfiddle, but you get the concept working. at the bottom of the html u can see i call countdown() parsing the current timestamp in miliseconds.

Comment: Get rid of occurrences of `<input type='hidden' name='submit' />` and try

Comment: yep, tried not that, thats for help gary neway. appreciate the explanations and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would try clearing the timeout first, then submitting the form, and after that displaying the alert:

```
if(Todays_Date >= Target_Date){
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $("form#testForm").submit();
    alert("Timeup, Submitting exam....");
}
```

I think the order in which you preformed operations was working against you.

Comment: ok, I have now tried this, and still getting same results :( thankyou though, i have added the whole countdown function code to my post, if that helps.

Comment: You keep calling the function which starts it all over again, by setting `var timeoutID` at the end, that might be it.

Comment: i dont quite follow. are you saying I need to declare my timeout before?

Comment: ok, currently now its not stuck in the loop hwoever it is still not submitting the form.

Comment: Well, whenever you preform an `alert()` it freezes the page, and your code, until the user dismisses the `alert`. Does it submit when your hit 'OK' on the `alert`?

Comment: no it doesn't submit. Also what I am lost on, is on submitting my form it should be navigating the user to add_responses.php....so why does the alert even pop up?